# Problems using Tkinter askopenfile

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I want to launch an "Open File" dialog in Tkinter in Python 2.7.

My code starts with:

```
from Tkinter import Frame, Tk, BOTH, Text, Menu, END
import tkFileDialog as tkfd
import fileinput
root = Tk()

global strTab
strTab = ""

def openTab(event):
    r = tkfd.askopenfilename()
    strTab = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', r).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

Later in the code I have:

```
btnLoadTab = Button(root,          
         text="Load Tab",      
         width=30,height=5,    
         bg="white",fg="black")

btnLoadTab.bind("<Button-1>", openTab)
btnLoadTab.pack()    
root.mainloop()
```

1. When I press the button an "Open File" dialog is shown, but when I select a file it closes and the button remains "clicked".
2. If I later call to `strTab` outside of `openTab`, it remains equal to "".

Comment: Please make your example runnable. A small runnable sample may seem excessive but it does a world of good towards getting good answers.

Comment: You shouldn't use `bind` with buttons. Buttons have a `command` attribute specifically for calling commands when you click.

Comment: Yes that remaining "clicked", is because you use bind to attach a command to the button. Use the `command` attribute.

Comment: You should remove `global strTab` as all global names are automatically global ;-).

Answer (score -1):

You can find workable example here: http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_dialogs.php